# Error 404 on Google Webmaster After Changing the CMS

Tags: seo, google-search-console

recently i changed my cms and my theme and i removed all pervious content. now in google webmaster i see that google is indexing my pervious site and in craw report give me 404 errors. how i can fix this issue without decreasing my seo score and google rank?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of the pages changed. The errors shown because these pages are not accessible anymore with the previous URLs. You need to create 301 redirects from your old pages to the new ones. After this, the errors you mentioned should disappear from Google Console (Webmaster Tools).

[Change page URLs with 301 redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en)